Importance of stationarity for ARIMA/ARIMAX/SARIMAX for predictive purposes
I am doing a forecasting project right now and I could use some understanding of why stationarity is importance when forecasting in general. Especially for the SARIMAX model.
I know the problem of spurious regression. For example, if both $y$ and $x$ are two independent random walks and we make a regression of $y$ on $x$, i.e. we fit $y = ax+b$, then we might get a p-value that is very low indicating that we are very certain that the value of $a \neq 0$, even though the true value is $0$.
But if I am not interested in any statistical inference and only about predictive power, why is stationarity important? I guess if we divide our data into training and test splits, where the training data is very much different from the test data, then this is a problem, since it is hard for the model to generalize. But if this isn't the case, why do we care about stationarity?
If anyone could give me some insights I would be thankful. Further, if any literature is available on the topic, references for this would be nice.
Thanks.

This thread contains pointers to references about forecasting: Resources/books for project on forecasting models The related but different subject of time series analysis (which is often a synonym for "ARIMA modeling") has references at Books for self-studying time series analysis?

Without some kind of assumption about the future distributions (such as stationarity, but not limited to that), how could you possibly do any forecasting at all?
